# How to use TIdSNMP to receive trap notifications from multiple sources

Tags: delphi, snmp, indy

We are developing a program in Delphi XE5 to monitor MFPs in a local network. It is important that for each incoming SNMP trap notification we are able to determine the MFP that sent it. It seems that TIdSNMP.ReceiveTrap places each notification that was received since the last call into an element of the TIdSNMP.Trap.Value array property; TIdSNMP.Trap.Host then contains the IP address of the MFP which sent the latest trap notification. Can somebody confirm this? Is there some way to obtain the IP addresses corresponding to the other elements of TIdSNMP.Trap.Value?

For testing purposes we are using the following code to receive and display SNMP trap messages:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdSNMP;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    IdSNMP1: TIdSNMP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

  procedure FormatTrap(ASnmpInfo : TSnmpInfo);
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('{');
    with ASnmpInfo do begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Host=%s, ', [Host]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Port=%d, ', [Port]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Enterprise=%s, ', [Enterprise]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('GenTrap=%d, ', [GenTrap]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SpecTrap=%d, ', [SpecTrap]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Version=%d, ', [Version]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('PDUType=%d, ', [PDUType]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('TimeTicks=%d, ', [TimeTicks]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ID=%d, ', [ID]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ErrorStatus=%d, ', [ErrorStatus]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ErrorIndex=%d, ', [ErrorIndex]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Community=%s, ', [Community]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ValueCount=%d, ', [ValueCount]));
      for i := 0 to ValueCount-1 do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('Value[%d]=%s, ', [i,Value[i]]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('ValueOID[%d]=%s, ', [i,ValueOID[i]]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('ValueType[%d]=%d, ', [i,ValueType[i]]));
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('}');
    end;
  end;

begin
  while not Application.Terminated do begin
    if IdSNMP1.ReceiveTrap() then begin
      FormatTrap(IdSNMP1.Trap);
    end;
    Sleep(100);
    Application.ProcessMessages();
  end;
end;

end.
```

Two MFPs -- a Konica Minolta bizhub C364e under 192.168.197.159 and a Konica Minolta bizhub C364 under 192.168.197.19 -- have been configured to send SNMP trap notifications to the computer this program is running on. Here are some sample results:

```
{
Host=192.168.197.159, 
Port=32884, 
Enterprise=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334, 
GenTrap=6, 
SpecTrap=10, 
Version=0, 
 PDUType=164, 
TimeTicks=7792839, 
ID=0, 
ErrorStatus=0, 
ErrorIndex=0, 
Community=public, 
ValueCount=5, 
Value[0]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[0]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[0]=4, 
 Value[1]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[1]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[1]=4, 
Value[2]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[2]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[2]=4, 
Value[3]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[3]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
 ValueType[3]=4, 
Value[4]=Job End, 
ValueOID[4]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[4]=4, 
}

{
Host=192.168.197.19, 
Port=53365, 
Enterprise=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334, 
GenTrap=6, 
SpecTrap=10, 
Version=0, 
 PDUType=164, 
TimeTicks=12469234, 
ID=0, 
ErrorStatus=0, 
ErrorIndex=0, 
Community=public, 
ValueCount=6, 
Value[0]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[0]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[0]=4, 
 Value[1]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[1]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[1]=4, 
Value[2]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[2]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[2]=4, 
Value[3]=No Paper, 
ValueOID[3]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
 ValueType[3]=4, 
Value[4]=Job End, 
ValueOID[4]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2, 
ValueType[4]=4, 
Value[5]=Job End, 
ValueOID[5]=1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.83.3.1, 
ValueType[5]=4, 
}
```

1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.105.2.2 is the SysObjectID for C364e and 1.3.6.1.4.1.18334.1.1.1.2.1.83.3.1 the SysObjectID for C364. So it seems that all but the very last notification comes from the MFP under 192.168.197.159, although for the last 6 notifications TIdSNMP.Trap.Host contains the value 192.168.197.19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe looks like a bug in `TIdSNMP.ReceiveTrap()`.  It is not calling `TIdSNMP.Trap.Clear()` each time.  It is not supposed to keep a history of received traps over time.  I have just checked in a fix into Indy's SVN.  If you do not want to, or cannot, upgrade your Indy install, a simple workaround would be to call `IdSNMP1.Trap.Clear()` before calling `IdSNMP1.ReceiveTrap()`:

```
while not Application.Terminated do begin
  IdSNMP1.Trap.Clear(); // <-- add this
  if IdSNMP1.ReceiveTrap() then begin
    FormatTrap(IdSNMP1.Trap);
  end;
  Sleep(100);
  Application.ProcessMessages();
end;
```

With that said, using a busy loop inside a UI click handler is not a good idea.  I would suggest you use a `TTimer` instead:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdUDPBase, IdUDPClient, IdSNMP;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button2: TButton;
    IdSNMP1: TIdSNMP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Timer1.Interval := 100;
  Timer1.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

  procedure FormatTrap(ASnmpInfo : TSnmpInfo);
  var
    i : integer;
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
    try
      Memo1.Lines.Add('{');
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Host=%s, ', [ASnmpInfo.Host]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Port=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.Port]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Enterprise=%s, ', [ASnmpInfo.Enterprise]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('GenTrap=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.GenTrap]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('SpecTrap=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.SpecTrap]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Version=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.Version]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('PDUType=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.PDUType]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('TimeTicks=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.TimeTicks]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ID=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.ID]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ErrorStatus=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.ErrorStatus]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ErrorIndex=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.ErrorIndex]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Community=%s, ', [ASnmpInfo.Community]));
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('ValueCount=%d, ', [ASnmpInfo.ValueCount]));
      for i := 0 to ASnmpInfo.ValueCount-1 do begin
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('Value[%d]=%s, ', [i,ASnmpInfo.Value[i]]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('ValueOID[%d]=%s, ', [i,ASnmpInfo.ValueOID[i]]));
        Memo1.Lines.Add( Format('ValueType[%d]=%d, ', [i,ASnmpInfo.ValueType[i]]));
      end;
      Memo1.Lines.Add('}');
    finally
      Memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;

begin
  IdSNMP1.Trap.Clear();
  if IdSNMP1.ReceiveTrap() then begin
    FormatTrap(IdSNMP1.Trap);
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and workaround/fix! One point I am still not quite clear on: What happens if 192.168.197.159 and 192.168.197.19 each send a trap notification within the same 100 millisecond interval? Does TIdSNMP simply discard the first one, or can I maybe call TIdSNMP.ReceiveTrap twice to receive the two messages?

Comment: You have to call `ReceiveTrap()` for each individual trap. Whether or not the traps get discarded is up to the OS, not Indy. SNMP uses UDP. If the socket's inbound buffer fills up before you read packets from it, subsequent UDP packets get dropped by the OS until the buffer clears.  But unless you are getting LOTS of traps in a short ampunt of time, that is not likely to happen with such a small sleep interval.

Comment: One thing you could try is have your loop/timer call `ReceiveTrap()` in a loop for as long as the socket still has pending data in its inbound buffer, then sleep only when the buffer has been exhausted. `TIdSNMP` does not expose access to its `fTrapRecvBinding` member, so you would have to expose that, then you can call its `Readable()` method (that is what `ReceiveTrap()` calls). Or just call `ReceiveTrap()` in a loop with a short `RecceiveTimeout` and break the loop when it returns false.

Comment: Okay, I think I will call ReceiveTrap in a loop as you describe. I assume I need to call TIdSNMP.Trap.Clear before every call to TIdSNMP.ReceiveTrap (not just at the beginning of the loop). Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Yes, `Clear()` it every time, unless you upgrade to the latest SVN version that fixes that.